# What's a good substitute for an enum?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a web service that returns different types of errors.
Each method can return one of the three basic types of errors:
`General`, `InvalidInput`, or `Non`.
In addition to those three possible values, each method can have it's own errors (e.g. for SignIn method - InvalidPassword) - but each method can return only one error.
So for example the SignIn method will be able to return one of the following error types: General, InvalidInput, Non, InvalidPassword.
At first I thought of using enums, but I now think that the error types should implement inheritance because there are the basic three types, and each new method's error types inherit from that.. But I can't really think how. I thought of using a static class - but then it will only have one string static field - and inheritance is irrelevant again...
Another problem with enums is that what the web service's client will get eventually is a meaningless int (through json)

So my question is: What is a good way of conveying the idea that there are three basic possible values, and you can add to those to make a new type of errors?

Answer (score 6):

It would be best if you reconsidered your interfaces.

It is by far better to use exceptions over error codes not only because it is so easy to forget about checking for an error code, but also because it is difficult to maintain them, keep them unique and meaningful.

John Saunders [states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251578/throwing-a-xml-web-service-exception-for-invalid-username-password/1251835#1251835) in a similar thread:

> [...] you should throw a `SoapException`. This will translate more or less directly into a SOAP Fault. A SOAP Fault is the appropriate way to indicate an error with a web service operation for the same reason that Exceptions are better than return status in a normal method - you don't have to check the return status at the point of the call.

Besides throwing a `SoapException` you may also throw arbitrary exceptions. ASP.NET will wrap these exceptions into a `SoapException` that gets passed to the client. The client can access the details of the exception in the inner exception of the `SoapException`.

For further explanations see also:

> **[Handling and Throwing Exceptions in XML Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds492xtk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)**

Comment: I really just graduated, and can't argue with you people but IMHO that's not a good solution - exceptions often hide real problems. I want my code to gracefully reach the return statement even if it's only in order to announce something went wrong along the way.. I'm quite sure I can find a famous pro programmer's blog post saying that.. Here it is- http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html . Or am I not getting you?

Comment: @Oren A: I wouldn't say that Joel is generally right here, but I believe he only refers to the kind of exception that Eric Lippert calls *vexing exception* in his [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx).

Comment: @0xA3, I think the OP might have a point in this particular use-case.  I think we can all agree that ordinary C# exceptions are the correct analog with respect to SoapExceptions.  I think it is certainly within reason for a SignIn method to actually return the result of the SignIn -- it's not going to return anything else.  An invalid username is actually not *exceptional*.  IMO, I only use exceptions when there is a **bug in the code** not due to invalid user input.

Comment: Ran out of space, but with all that being said, I agree with @0xA3 for his answer, because the OP had plans to use this pattern for all his methods, which I would not recommend.

Comment: Exceptions only ever hide real problems with a big waving red flag saying "there could be a problem over here". Mishandling exceptions can hide problems, but so roll-your-own-exception systems like this hide them too, along with the disadvantages of roll-your-own anything when there's a standard supported approach. The only advantage this has over normal exceptions, is avoiding the word "exception".

Comment: @Jon - Thanks a lot. Seems I'll be reconsidering my entire perception on exceptions.. Even more so after this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025790/why-does-nets-stringvalidators-validate-method-throws-an-exception-when-it-doe question of mine.. Thanks Kirk and 0xA3 too (-: